# option_groups_from_collection_for_select with include_blank option

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have some trouble here trying to include an include_blank option for 'option_groups_from_collection_for_select'
I would like to have include_blank option but have the currently selected value displayed instead of a blank selection on update action. I have tried this here but it still shows blank.

```
    select_tag(:candidate_source, option_groups_from_collection_for_select(grouped_candidate_sources, :second, :first, :id, :source), { :include_blank => true, :selected => :source })
```

Answer (score 0):

The last argument in the `option_groups_from_collection_for_select` is the selected option, which should map to your value.

Since your `option_key_method` (4th arg) is `:id` you're allowed to pass the form object directly as an argument. Example:

```
select_tag(:candidate_source, option_groups_from_collection_for_select(grouped_candidate_sources, :second, :first, :id, :source, f.object.source), { :include_blank => true }
```

Anyway, see here for more argument information: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/option_groups_from_collection_for_select